# Get remaining days from DateTime Diff

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following code, which creates a diff from two `DateTime` objects.

```
    $fd1=new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $fd2=new \DateTime();
    $fd2->setTimestamp($agreements[$i]->end_date);
    $diff = $fd2->diff($fd1);
```

I'm trying to derive the remaining days from `$fd1`, which is today, to `$fd2`, which is a date in the future.

Here's my attempt. It's faulty though, because some monthes have 30 days and some have 31

```
    $agreements[$i]->remaining_date = $diff->d+($diff->m*31)+($diff->y*365);
```

What i'm looking for is the correct number of days remaining from today to the end date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DateInterval::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) with the `a` format character, which will give you the total days between two `DateTime` objects:

```
$agreements[$i]->remaining_date = $diff->format('%a');
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uCWMq)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, something like this:

```
$fd1=new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$fd2=date_create("2020-02-10");
$diff=date_diff($fd1,$fd2);

echo $diff->format("Remaining days: %a.");
```

Try the code [here](https://paiza.io/projects/LwCJjZEUJs7pyx1uD8BxsA).